# How to join on nested belongs_to in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have three models, `Application`, which belongs to a `Board`, which belongs to a `User`.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :boards
end

class Board < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :applications
end

class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :board
end
```

I'm always only ever going to want to show the boards or applications for the current user. How can I say "show every application for the current board for the current user"? Basically how to query for something for specific parent id values.

Answer (score 3):

You should provide the current user id and board id at first.

```
user = User.find(user_id)           #get current user
board = user.boards.find(board_id)  #get current board
board.applications                  #get every application
```

You can get more info from [Rails Guide--Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Answer (score 2):

> show every application for the current board for `current_user`

The power of ActiveRecord should make this relatively simple:

```
board = current_user.boards.find params[:board_id]
board.applications #-> collection of Application objects for board
```

This assumes you're using `devise`, and thus have access to the `current_user` method.

If not, you'll be able to use something like the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users do
    resources :applications #-> url.com/users/:user_id/applications
end

#app/controllers/applications_controller.rb
class ApplicationsController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @user = User.find params[:user_id]
      @boards = @user.boards
   end
end

#app/views/applications/index.html.erb
<% @user.boards.each do |board| %>
   <%= board.name %>
      <% board.applications.each do |application| %>
         <%= application.name %>
      <% end %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

---

[**ORM**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)

I'll give you some context to this (hopefully it will help you in the future).

Firstly, you must understand that Rails is built on top of a *relational database* - or at least it should be. Relational databases use [`foreign_keys`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) to give you access to associative data objects:

[image]

Whilst this might not seem important, it explains the entire functionality of the [ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) system.

ActiveRecord is what's known as an *ORM* (Object Relationship Mapper)... in short, gives you the ability to populate *objects* with associative data from your relational database.

In the case of Ruby/Rails, the *object* orientated nature of ActiveRecord is a direct result of Ruby. That is, Ruby is an *object orientated* language; everything you do in it revolves around objects:

[image]

With Rails, those objects are built in the *models*.

Thus, if you want to understand how Rails works - you really need to get down to the *model* level -- you have to understand that calling `Model.find x` will *build* an object around that model, populating it with data from your database.

It's very clever.

The [*associations*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) are provided by ActiveRecord, and pulled through the relational database infrastructure. This means that you can call the likes of `@board = @user.boards.first` and populate with the correct data.

Here's a good demonstration of how it works:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd share about how running query with `ActiveRecord::Relation`. To know about query, no matter you want to show data that far away from the current table but when those have associations, those could be connected.

**Step by step to do query:**

1. Determine all relations tables

Here, you have to determine tables that related to its table associations. In this case: users, boards, and applications.

2. Determine the condition

You can put current_user is a condition. You need users, boards, applications

So the condition is:

```
User.joins(boards: :applications).where("users.id = ?", current_user.id)
```

**NOTE:**

I would try to explain. User joins boards because user has many boards. Next boards has many applications so we have to join boards with application into `boards: :applications`.

This is good explain for query has many through associations. [activerecord-query-through-multiple-joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19175084/activerecord-query-through-multiple-joins)