# Rails - How to use form_tag to search has_many_through associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am creating a search tab where users can search restaurants with a certain type. I have 3 models: Restaurant, Type, and RestaurantType. Since one restaurant can have multiple types, I created a RestaurantType relations table.

**How can I create such search tab?**

The StackOverflow question I found closest to this was the following: [ActiveRecord query through multiple joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19175084/activerecord-query-through-multiple-joins), but it does not cover all I need. That said, I am still very new to Rails and maybe just need a more guided answer.

**restaurant.rb**

```
has_many :types, :through => :restaurant_types
```

**type.rb**

```
has_many :restaurants, :through => :restaurant_types
```

**restaurant_type.rb**

```
belongs_to :restaurant
belongs_to :type
```

**restaurants_controller.rb (index action)** (I'm also implementing search by name, which is an attribute of Restaurant)

```
@restaurants = Restaurant.joins(restaurant_type: :type).where 
    ("cast(type_id as text) LIKE ?", "%#{params[:type]}%")
@restaurants = @restaurants.where("restaurant_name LIKE ?", 
    "%#{params[:restaurant_name]}%").paginate(:page => params[:page], 
    :per_page => 8)
```

**restaurants/index.html.erb** (only the search part)

```
<%= form_tag(restaurants_path, :method => 'get') do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :restaurants_name, params[:restaurants_name], :placeholder => "Name" %>
    <%= select_tag :restaurant_type_id, options_for_select(Type.all.map{ |t| [t.type_name, t.id] }) %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

**Notes:**

1. I added the "has_many ... :through => ..." associations manually after the migrations, and don't know if they count in this case.
2. I am getting the following error when I reach the index: **"Association named 'restaurant_type' was not found on Restaurant"**, which refers to the third line in my index page.

-

### **LOOKS NASTY, BUT SOLVED IT**

**restaurants_controller.rb**

```
def index

    @types = RestaurantType.where("type_id LIKE ?", "%#{params[:type_id]}%")
    array = []
    @types.each do |t|
        @restaurant = Restaurant.find(t.restaurant_id)
        array.push(@restaurant)
    end
    @restaurant = WillPaginate::Collection.create(1, 6, array.length) do |pager|
      pager.replace array
    end
end
```

**restaurants/index.html.erb (part of the form_tag)**

```
<%= select_tag :type_id, options_for_select(Type.all.map{ |t| [t.type_name, t.id] }) %>
```

-

### **ANOTHER EDIT -- WORKS BETTER AND TOGETHER WITH OTHER SEARCH PARAMETERS**

```
if (params[:type_id].to_f > 0)
    array = []
    RestaurantType.where("type_id = #{ params[:type_id] } ").each do |t|
        array.push(t.school_id)
    end
    @restaurants = Restaurant.where("restaurant_name LIKE ? AND cast(city_id as text) LIKE ? AND id in (?)", "%#{ params[:restaurant_name] }%", 
       "%#{params[:city_id]}%", array).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 6)

else
    @restaurants = Restaurant.where("restaurant_name LIKE ? AND cast(city_id as text) LIKE ?", "%#{params[:restaurant_name]}%", 
       "%#{params[:city_id]}%").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 6)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to create an array with all the restaurants with the selected Type. The algorithm goes over each object (restaurant_type) with the selected type, pushes it into an array, and paginates the array on the index.

It may take longer, but asymptotic analysis suggests T(n) is multiplied by a constant, which isn't that big a deal.

And thank you to the dude who answered here about paginating arrays: [Paginating an Array in Ruby with Will_Paginate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187076/paginating-an-array-in-ruby-with-will-paginate)

**restaurants_controller.rb**

```
def index

    @types = RestaurantType.where("type_id LIKE ?", "%#{params[:type_id]}%")
    array = []
    @types.each do |t|
        @restaurant = Restaurant.find(t.restaurant_id)
        array.push(@restaurant)
    end
    @restaurant = WillPaginate::Collection.create(1, 6, array.length) do |pager|
      pager.replace array
    end
end
```

**restaurants/index.html.erb (part of the form_tag)**

```
<%= select_tag :type_id, options_for_select(Type.all.map{ |t| [t.type_name, t.id] }) %>
```

-

### **ANOTHER EDIT -- WORKS BETTER AND TOGETHER WITH OTHER SEARCH PARAMETERS**

```
if (params[:type_id].to_f > 0)
    array = []
    RestaurantType.where("type_id = #{ params[:type_id] } ").each do |t|
        array.push(t.school_id)
    end
    @restaurants = Restaurant.where("restaurant_name LIKE ? AND cast(city_id as text) LIKE ? AND id in (?)", "%#{ params[:restaurant_name] }%", 
       "%#{params[:city_id]}%", array).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 6)

else
    @restaurants = Restaurant.where("restaurant_name LIKE ? AND cast(city_id as text) LIKE ?", "%#{params[:restaurant_name]}%", 
       "%#{params[:city_id]}%").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 6)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is coming from the join in restaurants_controller:

```
@restaurants = Restaurant.joins(restaurant_type: :type).where("cast(type_id as text) LIKE ?", "%#{params[:type]}%")
```

You must use the exact same name as you specified in the model...in this case, 'restaurant_types' instead of 'restaurant_type'.

However, you have already created the associations between your models in the model files, so you do not need to use a join. You can search this way:

```
@restaurants = Type.find(params[:restaurant_type_id]).restaurant.where('restaurant_name like ?', "%#{params[:restaurant_name]}%")
```

I would change the association in type.rb to:

```
has_many :restaurants, :through => :restaurant_types
```

Then the method to find restaurants from a type would be plural, and more intuitive.

Comment: "Couldn't find Type with 'id'="