# Rails 5 - Activerecord association query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have two models associated with each other as follows.

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord 
    belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments
end
```

Following record query

```
comments_list = Comment.where(:post_id => post_id, :is_delete => false).joins(:user).select('comments.*,users.*')
```

Generates the following mysql query in logger

```
SELECT comments.*,users.* FROM `comments` INNER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `comments`.`user_id` WHERE `comments`.`post_id` = '81' AND `comments`.`is_delete` = 0.
```

This seems generating very ligitimate query, but comments_list object contain columns only from comments table.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do, if you want to display the username next to the comment, Mert B.'s answer is fine, all you have to do is `include(:user)` and the users from the comment list will be fetched along when you do something like this:

```
comments_list = Comment.where(:post_id => post_id, :is_delete => false).joins(:user).select('comments.*,users.*')
comments_list.each do |comment|
  puts "#{comment.text} by #{comment.user.name}"
end
```

Or maybe if you want only users who have at least one comment, you can always select users from the user_ids on the comments table:

```
User.where(id: Comment.select(:user_id))
```

Comment: yes @Macelo Risoli - it worked, thanks. So this means i have  to translate the result if i am doing this query in controller to return response back to client(browser), building another hash by iterating through a loop

Comment: first answer - last para http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19175084/activerecord-query-through-multiple-joins