# Rails 5.1 - Display list ordered by associated value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, join

I want to list game stats (Participantstats) belonging to players (Players) and sort the list according to the first name (first_name) of the player. Many Players play many Games. The join table is Participants. Each Participant record has an associated (single) Participantstat record.

I have tried all sort of different syntax but this line in the controller is failing:

```
@pstats = Participantstat.includes(:participant, :player).order('participant.player.first_name')
```

The error is

> PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column participantstats.player_id does not exist

If I remove the .order part, it works but naturally I don't get the records showing up in the right order in the subsequent view template.

Here are the relevant parts of the models:

```
class Player < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :participants, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :participantstats, through: :participants
  has_many :games, through: :participants
end

class Participant < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :game
  has_one :participantstat, dependent: :destroy
  delegate :first_name, to: :player
end

class Participantstat < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :participant
  belongs_to :player
  delegate :player, to: :participant, allow_nil: true
  delegate :first_name, to: :participant
end

class Game < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :participants, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :players, through: :participants
end
```

And here is the relevant fragment of the schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20180823002200) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "games", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "plays"
  end

  create_table "participants", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "player_id"
    t.bigint "game_id"
    t.string "team"
  end

  create_table "participantstats", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "result"
    t.integer "fga", default: 0
    t.integer "fgm", default: 0
    t.integer "pts", default: 0
    t.bigint "participant_id"
  end

  create_table "players", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "email"
  end

  add_foreign_key "participants", "games", on_delete: :cascade
  add_foreign_key "participants", "players", on_delete: :cascade
end
```

As you can see above, I also tried using delegate statements (and code which I have since deleted) to get the result but without success.

Here is the SQL generated, FWIW:

> : SELECT "participantstats"."id" AS t0_r0, "participantstats"."result" AS t0_r1, "participantstats"."fga" AS t0_r2, "participantstats"."fgm" AS t0_r3, "participantstats"."pts" AS t0_r4, "participantstats"."reb" AS t0_r5, "participantstats"."ass" AS t0_r6, "participantstats"."stl" AS t0_r7, "participantstats"."blk" AS t0_r8, "participantstats"."seconds" AS t0_r9, "participantstats"."score" AS t0_r10, "participantstats"."participant_id" AS t0_r11, "participants"."id" AS t1_r0, "participants"."player_id" AS t1_r1, "participants"."game_id" AS t1_r2, "participants"."created_at" AS t1_r3, "participants"."updated_at" AS t1_r4, "participants"."team" AS t1_r5, "players"."id" AS t2_r0, "players"."first_name" AS t2_r1, "players"."last_name" AS t2_r2, "players"."email" AS t2_r3, "players"."mobile" AS t2_r4, "players"."notify" AS t2_r5, "players"."created_at" AS t2_r6, "players"."updated_at" AS t2_r7, "players"."shirt" AS t2_r8, "players"."shorts" AS t2_r9, "players"."role" AS t2_r10 FROM "participantstats" LEFT OUTER JOIN "participants" ON "participants"."id" = "participantstats"."participant_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "players" ON "players"."id" = "participantstats"."player_id" ORDER BY participants.players.first_name

Comment: Thanks, @Gabbar. Neither of those suggestions makes any difference. The error message is the same.

Comment: I wish that were the case but as I've already explained, it doesn't. I've added the SQL generated to the OP.

Comment: have you tried without delegate? `Participantstat.includes(participant: :player).order('players.first_name')`

Comment: Yes, @Krupa Suthar, I have just tied that (again). I get the sense that this error is due to Rails not understanding how to join the Participantstats table to the Players table. From Participantstats' perspective, it "belongs_to :player" but since one can't have a "belongs_to X, though:" association, it can't bridge the middle link through Participants...

Comment: The line which is causing an error is `belongs_to:  player` in Participantstat model because schema doesn't have player_id column in participantstats.
Remove that line from model and after that try `Participantstat.includes(participant: :player).order('players.first_name')`

Comment: Thanks, @Krupa Suthar. Your last sentence is correct. See 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19175084/activerecord-query-through-multiple-joins which I have been reading in the interim and has led me to the same conclusion. The "belongs_to: player" line is a red herring and doesn't affect the result. If you'd like to write up the answer below, I can attribute the answer to you. Would be great if you could include a link to where this obscure syntax is documented!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your schema doesn't have player_id in `participantstats` table that's why you cannot directly associate `player` with `Participantstat` model, so remove `belongs_to :player` line from `Participantstat` model.

After that, you can get player with nested joins like below,

```
Participantstat.includes(participant: :player).order('players.first_name')
```

For more information, you can use this link:
  [nested joins](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-multiple-associations)